# Reduce number of plots in sns.pairplot()

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I am following the tutorial from [this website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression) and I am trying to visualize the sequential model `df`.

Here is my code:

```
# LAST MODIFIED: December 10, 2018
# NOTE: The loss function is used to optimize your model. This is the function that will get minimized by the optimizer.
#       A metric is used to judge the performance of your model. This is only for you to look at and has nothing to do
#       with the optimization process.
#       "val" refers to "validation" AKA testing dataset

# LIBRARY AND PACKAGE IMPORTING
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz;
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
TFVersion = tf.__version__
newline = "\n"
noisePatience = 400
# Hyper-parameters
EPOCHS = 1000
learningRate = 0.001
HLneuronFrequency = [128, 64]
trainDataPercentage = 80
testDataPercentage = 100 - trainDataPercentage


# FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
def ThreeDimenDisplay(x_axis_data, y_axis_data, z_axis_data):
    # THE 3D PLOTS
    # Make the plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_trisurf(y_axis_data, x_axis_data, z_axis_data, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, linewidth=0.2)
    plt.show()
    # to Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
    surf = ax.plot_trisurf(y_axis_data, x_axis_data, z_axis_data, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, linewidth=0.2)
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()
    # Rotate it
    ax.view_init(30, 45)
    plt.show()
    # Other palette
    ax.plot_trisurf(y_axis_data, x_axis_data, z_axis_data, cmap=plt.cm.jet, linewidth=0.01)
    plt.show()


# CONFIGURATIONS ------------------------

# SOFTWARE CHECKING
print(newline)
print("Current version of TensorFlow: ", TFVersion)

# FOR BEST-VISUALIZATIONS (OVERWRITES MATPLOTLIB)
sns.set()

# Downloading the Boston Housing Data Set - it is already present in the keras
# NOTE: This will be referred to as the "BHD"
boston_housing = keras.datasets.boston_housing

# Initializing the training + testing data and labels as per the information suggested in the BHD
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = boston_housing.load_data()

# Shuffle the training set in order to assure randomness - this condition is required for any statistical analysis
order = np.argsort(np.random.random(train_labels.shape))
train_data = train_data[order]
train_labels = train_labels[order]

# Printing the training and testing data sets (the .shape member function gets the examples and feature frequency
# from the train_data vector instance)
print("Training set: {}".format(train_data.shape))  # 404 examples, 13 features
print("Testing set:  {}".format(test_data.shape))  # 102 examples, 13 features

# Initializing the variables/attributes for the data-set
column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD',
                'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
Pcolumn_names = []
df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=column_names)
df.head()

sns.pairplot(df)
```

When I currently run the aforementioned code, I get a huge list of comparisons with some trivial numbers on the side:
[image: Output of Python Run Command]

Since this is obviously too much data at once, how can I reduce the number of plots and actually know what the function is actually comparing (i.e. the x and y axes)?

Answer (score 4):

You can select some columns on your dataframe and then do the pairplot. If you check [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) you would see that it can be done using the *vars* parameter:

```
sns.pairplot(df, vars=[columns_names])
```

If you don´t know which columns to select and want to plot all variables pairwise, you could do combinations of the dataframe columns names but keep in mind that you will end up with a lot (n! / r! / (n-r)!) of plots:

```
from itertools import combinations
number_of_variables = 6
for columns_names in combinations(df.columns, number_of_variables):
    sns.pairplot(df, vars=[columns_names])
```

Comment: Hello Javier! Thank you for your response! Your code seems to make sense to me and I tried to implement it. I wrote: `from itertools import combinations number_of_variables = 3
for columns_names in combinations(df.columns, number_of_variables):
    sns.pairplot(df, vars=['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS'])`. However, although I get the result, this is taking an exceedingly long time to interpret and I end up with over 286 different figure windows with the exact same plots. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are always using the same vars. An updated version of the code would be the following:
    `from itertools import combinations
    number_of_variables = 2
    for c in combinations(column_names, number_of_variables):
        sns.pairplot(df, vars=c)
        filename='_'.join(c)
        plt.savefig(filename+'.png')
        plt.close()`
Depending on the number of variables that you want to compare at once the number of plots varies.
[Here you can check the number of plots vs the number of variables][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjpr8.png

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, instead of plotting all combinations as a full pairplot (that leads to a lot of repeated plots!), let's instead plot rows of plots so that we only have each versus pair repeated twice (for *n* columns we have *n<sup>2</sup>* plots).

The key here is to use the `x_vars` and `y_vars` arguments to pairplots to customize what we show in each invocation. We can use it to show all *n<sup>2</sup>* combinations without adding anything extra.

In my example I have one column that's used for the hue that I remove before starting. This is from a Jupyter notebook, so because there are so many plots, I have markdown sections for each variable and each line.

```
from IPython.display import Markdown
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# `df` already in scope as the pandas dataframe with data

hue = 'label'
vars_per_line = 5
all_vars = list(df.columns.symmetric_difference([hue]))

for var in all_vars:
    rest_vars = list(all_vars)
    rest_vars.remove(var)
    display(Markdown(f"## {var}"))
    while rest_vars:
        line_vars = rest_vars[:vars_per_line]
        del rest_vars[:vars_per_line]
        line_var_names = ", ".join(line_vars)
        display(Markdown(f"### {var} vs {line_var_names}"))
        sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=line_vars, y_vars=[var], hue=hue, palette='bright', )
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
```

Output looks something like the following (but continues scrolling):

[image: Aspect etc scatterplots]